# Swift 2.1 DatePicker NSDate Error Nil Unwrapping Optional Value?

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift2

I have a class that I'm trying to set a begin and end date in:

```
class Dates {
    var beginDateTime = NSDate()
    var endDateTime = NSDate()    
}
```

And in my View Controller I create an instance of it:

```
var dates: Dates!
```

I also have two date pickers:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker1: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker2: UIDatePicker!
```

Then when trying to set these times in a navigation segue...

```
dates.beginDateTime = datePicker1.date
dates.endDateTime = datePicker2.date
```

I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

There's no optional value here... I don't understand. The dates are set. Why am I getting this error? There are no nil values here.  I even tested them in a print(datePicker1.date) command, they're set for sure.

In fact I have additional code in a function here to programmatically set the dates for the user on viewDidLoad, which works fine:

```
func setDatePicker(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    datePicker.minimumDate = NSDate()
    let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: NSDate())
    if count > 0 {
        components.hour = 23
        components.minute = 30
    } else {
        components.hour = 19
        components.minute = 00
    }
    let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
    count++
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are set in your date picker but your `dates` object is probably nil. You have just declared the `dates` object, so unless you allocate memory and initialise it, it will be nil. Do

```
var dates = Dates()
```

That will fix that error